# I want to upload file containing Hindi language words and English words to phpMyadmin but getting errors

Tags: xampp, localhost, hindi

I want to upload file containing Hindi language words and English words to phpMyadmin but getting errors.
 All columns are importing into one row and `????` marks are appearing instead of Hindi text.

Please help me. I have tried everything.

The data is like this:

```
hindi        english                  englis1

 ساتھ        together                 togetherr
جانا           go                       gone
```

hindi , english and english1 are column names

Other field are data. The  data is in a .csv file.

Comment: Could you be return the structure (and the collection) of your MySql tables ?

Comment: You have not uploaded your image properly. Please try again, if you wish the image to be displayed. You can add it using the [edit] button.